# Upload files to AWS S3 takes a lot of CPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently working on a server app (JEE) and getting some problems to upload files to AWS S3. I'm using the Java SDK (S3client.putObject) to upload these files. When the server starts, everything happens as expected. Files are generated in the server (EC2 instance) and uploaded to S3 in a few seconds. But after some days, the performance degrades a lot. Files that usually took 5 or 6 seconds to be uploaded need now 10 to 30 minutes (yes, minutes). I profiled the app and the culprit here is the section that does the upload using the AWS Java SDK. Strangely  the CPU utilization goes near 100% and stays there for minutes. As this is basically an IO operation, I don't understand why it may need so many CPU cyles to run.
Has anyone eve experienced this behavior?
Any tips on where to look?

PS: file size goes from 1 to 50 MB.

Thanks a lot!

Updates:
The EC2 instance that creates the files and uploads them to S3 is m1.large.
I'm using the 1.6.4 AWS SDK version .

Comment: will the time to upload files go back down to "5 or 6 seconds" eventually even if you don't restart the app?

Comment: No, it doesn't go back. I need to restart the app server

Comment: If you're using SSL for S3, you may look into AES-NI if you've already taken other steps to optimizing S3 performance.

Comment: @CleversonSchmidt It sounds like you have a resource-leak of some sort

Comment: @HyperAnthony If AES-NI is the problem, shouldn't happen every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any reason why the SDK code would cause your CPU to go so high.  My first guess would be some sort of garbage collection issue.  When you upload your data, are you passing in a File object to AmazonS3.putObject, or some sort of stream (including FileInputStream)?  Streams can be a little tricky to deal with, since they aren't guaranteed to be repeatable and you have to explicitly provide the Content-Length in the ObjectMetadata as part of your upload, otherwise the SDK has to buffer your upload in memory to calculate the total length.  That'd be the very first thing I'd recommend checking out.

On a side note.. you should check out the [TransferManager API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) in the SDK.  It gives you a nice simple interface to uploading and downloading files to/from Amazon S3, and have several optimizations built in.

If that still doesn't turn up a clue, then I'd recommend making a dead simple repro case for this.  Write a single class file that simply uploads a random File to the same S3 key, and leave that running for the same duration as your application code.  If you're able to reproduce the problem in that simple setup, then we can take a look at the code and help get it debugged, but with all the other variables involved in your full application code, we can't do much more than guess at what could be happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm passing an Inputstream to AmazonS3.putObject and setting the content lenght. I will check the TransferManager API and see if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in AWS SDK for .NET. Uploading a 50GB file to S3 loads 100% cpu usage.

I profiled the app.

Turns out, That's because all AWS API requests have to be "signed", and a file - especially a big one - is sent via multiple requests & chunks, sometimes thousands, some of them simultaneous. Every request is then hashed via SHA256 and signed using IAM credentials.

Limit the number of concurrent threads, disable httpS (use http), limit the number of chunks, increase the chunk size etc etc. By doing that you can ease the load, but it will still use about 20-30% on a fast connection :(( (even if you're sending from EC2 to S3 in the same region, which **is** a very fast connection)